# Loop through each element under "Data"

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm using Kucoin's API to get a list of coins.

Here is the endpoint: https://api.kucoin.com/v1/market/open/coins

And here's my code:

```
$kucoin_coins = file_get_contents('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/market/open/coins');
$kucoin_coins = json_decode($kucoin_coins, true);

print_r($kucoin_coins);
```

I can see how to target one coin like so:

```
echo "name: " . $kucoin_coins['data'][0]['name'];
```

But I can't see how to loop through them.

How can I loop through each of the "coins" returned here? They are under the "data" part that is returned. I'm sorry, I'm just not seeing how to do it right now. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `foreach ($kucoin_coins['data'] as $coin)`? Also, please include the output of the file_get_contents into the question to make it visible for everyone. (Just two coins should be enough).

Comment: Yea, I was actually just about to update it with this exact response. Thanks!

foreach ($kucoin_coins['data'] as $coin) {
 echo $coin['name']; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the decoded elements using the `foreach` command:

```
foreach ($kucoin_coins['data'] as $coin) {
    //do your magic here.
}
```

But I usually prefer using `json_decode($kucoin_coins)` rather than the one for arrays. I believe this:

```
$item->attribute;
```

Is easier to write than this one:

```
$item['attribute'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($kucoin_coins['data'] as $data) {
    echo $data['name']."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your data using [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) like this

```
<?php
$kucoin_coins = file_get_contents('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/market/open/coins');
$kucoin_coins = json_decode($kucoin_coins, true);
print '<pre>';
print_r($kucoin_coins);
print '</pre>';
foreach($kucoin_coins['data'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $value['name']. "<br/>"; 
}
?>
```

**See DEMO:** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q6kt-dctg